# Wordpress multisite Nginx redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm pretty sure this is just a basic config thing. I've got a wordpress multisite up and running, with base domains. I want to implement simple domain mapping, unfortunately the Wordpress documentation for nginx config is pretty lacking.

I tried and succeeded doing this using the [WU Domain Mapping plugin](https://odd.blog/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) 9 months ago, but it isn't working this time round, and I'd rather have it working without the plugin (aiming for a low plugin WP installation).

Of course, I've amended the site URL in the sites section to test this.

What I currently have is:

```
site1.com (working)
site2.site1.com (working)
site2.com (301 redirect loop)
```

What I want is:

```
site1.com
site2.com
```

Any suggestions what I need to add to my Nginx conf file? My current nginx conf file is pretty much the same as that of the [Digital Ocean Docker](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose) set up page:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;


        server_name *.site1.com site1.com www.site1.com;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }


        error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        }

server {

        error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name site1.com www.site1.com;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.com/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

UPDATE:

Checking in the nginx Docker if I log in and run the `nginx` command, I get these error messages :
*EDIT - this is also happening on the working configuration so I'm guessing it may be a red herring*

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/03/18 10:07:11 [emerg] 29#29: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/03/18 10:07:11 [emerg] 29#29: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/03/18 10:07:11 [emerg] 29#29: bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/03/18 10:07:11 [emerg] 29#29: still could not bind()
```

Inside the container, *netstat* gives me this for ports 80/443:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.2:38422        199.232.138.132:80      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
```

Outside the container it seems to be correctly running just 1 port:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1298/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1313/docker-proxy
```

EDIT (18/3/21):

Just did a restore from a working back up at another IP address and I'm still having issues with this particular domain. Funnily enough, I span up another site with a different domain and that one is working!

I'll check the config to see if there's anything in there that's different, if not, I think I need to go down the DNS route, checking whether that's correctly aimed at my host or not.

Comment: Seems you don't have server_name configuration for site2.com, can you check that?

Comment: I did try that, as in `server_name *.site1.com site1.com www.site1.com *.site2.com site2.com www.site2.com;` for both the 80 and 443 port sections, it's currently still set up like that and still redirecting.

Comment: Can you check your theme functions.php and add ```remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');``` line?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work on either of 2021 or 2019 basic themes. Hey thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Holy crapola what a palaver that was. A couple of days of d**king around on this and it turns out its an Cloudflare SSL thing. Did notice this today but didn't pick up on it.

Things were point to DNS/SSL but wasn't sure what it might be. Found a reference to Cloudflare SSL settings [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-multisite-too-many-redirects-on-wp-admin/), in the site's SSL/TLS settings I had the **encryption mode** set to *flexible* and they should have been *full*. Set it and it's working now. I've a feeling I've already solved this problem, better make a clearer note about it this time!